# Check array of objects for a specific property value

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a small program where I have a page with two input fields and a user can enter their name and the number of calories they've eaten today. After a person enters their data, I want to display it alongside other people's data in a list sorted by total calories.

I also want that person to be able to re-enter their name and additional calories and have it update their total calories (as opposed to creating another entry with their name and most recent calorie amount).

I am assigning the input values to variables, using those to create a new Person object, then pushing that object to an array.

How can I test to see if the array contains a Person object with a name that already exists? My test isn't recognizing names that have already been submitted. If a person's name has already been entered, I'd like to update their total calories instead of creating a new Person object.

My javascript code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    /* Person object constructor */
    function Person(name, calories) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    function addToList() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var calories = document.getElementById('calories').value;

        /* 
            Check to see if list already contains person's name
            If yes, update their calorie amount.
            If not, create a new player and add them to the list.
         */

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] === name) {
                alert('This person already exists.');
            } else {
                var newPerson = new Person(name, calories);
                list.push(newPerson);
            }   
        }
    }

    var list = [];
    $('#add').click(addToList);

})();
```

Comment: Is the question "how do I check if the person already exists in the list", or "how do I modify the person if they already exist in the list"? I ask because, your code already checks if the person exists in the list (unless I'm misreading).

Comment: If you plan on building on your example I suggest try giving the Person an ID property or email.. because you can have multiple people with the same names.

Comment: Pricey, that's a great idea; I'll look into that as well, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is a `list` of `Person` (if `rankings.push` is meant to be `list.push`) so when you are doing `(list[i] === name)` that is trying to compare a `Person` object to a string literal. Try doing `(list[i].name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're storing names inside of the array `list`, however these names are never being ADDED to `list`. Instead you appear to be using another array called `rankings`.

```
rankings.push(newPerson);
list.push(name);
```

And since you already have an array that stores people, `rankings`, maybe you should iterate over that?

```
var foundPerson = false;
for (var i = 0; i < rankings.length; i++) {
    if (rankings[i].name === name) {
        alert('This person already exists.');

        // do your update
        rankings[i].calories = calories;

        // set flag so we know we actually found a person
        foundPerson = true;
        break;
    } 
}

// if no person found, add new person
if (!foundPerson) {
    var newPlayer = new Person(name, calories);
    rankings.push(newPerson);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bucky, I did have two typos I created when I transcribed and simplified my code to post here, now edited. I'll try out your suggestion.